# SwiftUI how to create custom property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know we have properties that can be modified below our view initialization in SwiftUI such as `.disabled`

Example:

```
Button {
    print("Something")
} label: {
    Text("Something")
}.disabled(true)
```

I want to know if it possible to create my own `.disabled` for example: if I create a custom view, I want to create the `.selected` property but I don't want to use it in the initialization of the view, I want to use just like `.disabled` is used.

Ex:

```
CustomView(oneProperty:someValue)
    .selected(true)
```

In other words... can I create my own `.disabled`?

Comment: yes you can, it's called `ViewModifier`. Have a look at this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier There is also quite a bit of info on this in various SO posts.

Answer (score 0):

Modifier is just a function, so we can create it a function of our custom type, like

```
public struct CustomView: View {
    public let oneProperty: String

    private let selected: Bool     // << here !!

    public var body: some View {
        Text(oneProperty)
            .background(selected ? Color.blue : Color.clear)
    }

    public func selected(_ state: Bool) -> Self {
        CustomView(oneProperty: oneProperty, selected: state)  // << here !!

//  Alternate possible variant:
//      var newView = self
//      self.selected = state
//      return newView

    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5